# ZFS: FS consistency with partial disk backups

Tags: backup, zfs, data-consistency

Suppose I have a zpool with a single disk and some datasets, some files written to them, and a snapshot `snap-1`.
Now I create a raw image `t-1.img` of the disk.
Afterwards, I write some more files, create another snapshot `snap-2` and create a new image `t-2.img`.

If I now partially update `t-1.img` with the contents of `t2.img`, e.g. due to an aborted `rsync --inplace`, do I get any guarantees about the consistency of the file systems on that inconsistent disk image? I obviously don't expect anything about `snap-2` or files written afterwards, but can I expect to be able to read the data from `snap-1`, since it is read-only and present in both images?

Also, does it in this scenario make any difference whether the pool is unmounted before the backup images are created?
Do some ZFS options, e.g. deduplication, compression, or encryption, affect the outcome?